# Rails: Submit html table content in form to controller

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have some trouble with an rails formular.

I have a form to create "projects".

**Project form**

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@project) do |f| %>
...
<div class="container-fluid">   
    <%= f.static_control label:"Vordefinierte Aufgaben" do %>

    <div class="actions form-group nopadding">
      <div class="center-block">
        <%=link_to "", data: {toggle:"modal", target:".newTask-modal"} , class: "btn btn-success center-block btn-sidebar-ok", id: "singlebutton"  do%>
          <i> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-left btn-sidebar-icon"></span>Neue Aufgabe hinzufügen </i>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="task-table">
        <%=render 'tasks/table'%>
    </div>

<% end %>
</div> 
...
<!-- task Modal to create a new task -->    
   <%=render 'tasks/newTaskModal' %>
<% end %>


  <!-- Button -->
              <div class="actions form-group">
                <div class="center-block">
                  <%= button_tag( type: 'submit',  class: "btn btn-success center-block btn-sidebar-ok", id: "singlebutton")  do%>
                    <i> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-left"></span>Projekt anlegen </i>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Within this form a have a table which shows created tasks and a button to open an bootstrap modal. This modal contains a new form to create a task.

**Task Form within modal**

```
 <%= bootstrap_form_tag() do |f| %>

        <div class="col-sm-8"> 
            <%= f.text_field :task_title, label: "Titel", placeholder: "Betreff", icon: "pencil",wrapper: { class: 'icon-addon addon-md'} %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"> 
            <%= f.number_field :task_in_min, label: "Arbeitszeit in Min", placeholder: "Bsp.: 25", icon: "time",  wrapper: { class: 'icon-addon addon-md'}%>            
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12"> 
            <%= f.text_area :task_description, label: "Beschreibung*", placeholder: "Aufgabenbeschreibung", icon: "pencil", rows: 10, wrapper: { class: 'icon-addon addon-md'}%>
        </div>


            <%= button_tag( type: 'button',  id:"taskSubmit", class: "btn btn-success center-block btn-sidebar-ok")  do %>
                <i > <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-left btn-sidebar-icon"></span> Speichern  </i>
            <% end %>


 <% end %>
```

If I click to "taskSubmit" a javascript put this task (title, description, min) into the table within the project form. JS create a new table row with the task content.

**Javascript**

```
//take data from task form and at a new task element to the task table in project form
$(function TaskSubmitFunction(){
$('#taskSubmit').click(function(){

    var task_title = $('#task_title').val();
    var task_description = $('#task_description').val();
    var task_in_min = $('#task_in_min').val();
    //Remove spaces from title
    var id = task_title.replace(/ /g,'');

    $('#taskTable tr:last').after('<tr id="task_'+id+'"> <td>'+task_title+'</td> <td>'+task_description+'</td><td>'+task_in_min+'</td><td> <span class="pull-right"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Löschen"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-colored delete-position" id="'+id+'"name="button" type="button" task="'+task_title+'"><i><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"/></i></button></span></span></td></tr>');

    $('#taskTable').after('<input type="hidden" id="1" name="1" value="'+task_title+'" />');

    $('#task_title').val('');
    $('#task_description').val('');
    $('#task_in_min').val('');


    //initialize task delete
    $(function TaskDeleteFunction(){
        $('#'+id).click(function(){

            var task_title = $(this).attr('task');

            if (confirm("Soll die Aufgabe wirklich gelöscht werden?")) {
                $('#'+id).remove();
            }
            return false;
        });
    });


});
});
```

What I want to do now is to submit these table elements to the project controller to create the project and all necessary tasks activeRecords. Is this possible?
How can I do this? Maybe create a hidden field for every table element which will be submit to the project form? But every table element consists of three values... how can I do this?

Do you have any idea?

best regards

Comment: You seem to be on the right track, although I can't seem to find the submit button for your main form.  Assuming it is there, are the tasks not showing up in `params` when you submit the form?

Comment: I've added the submit-button code. But how can I create a hidden field for a task (which consists of 3 values) so that I submit it to the project controller?

Comment: Just use the Rails `hidden_field_tag` helper (documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag)).

Comment: Thx but my problem is how can I submit 3 values over one hidden_field_tag? Is it possible to create an array and put this to the hidden field? :) Do you know how?

Comment: I suppose that may be possible, but why not just use three hidden fields (one for each value)?  Straightforward and they will be easy to access in the params hash.

Comment: Yes thats the solution. Thx. I just didn't know how to do that. But now I get it. :)

Comment: Glad to help.  I'll post as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use three hidden fields (one for each value)? Straightforward and they will be easy to access in the params hash.